# Custom Magento Admin View

Tags: php, magento, admin

We currently are setting up a system with Simple and Grouped products, each of the simple products have names such as strawberry, chocolate.

The grouped product has the full product name. This has been done because I have developed a front end interface to allow for a wholesale style shopping experience,

Now in the backend when looking at the orders it obviously shows the SKU and then the product name which is Strawberry or Chocolate, Is there a way of showing the grouped product also above each of the simple products?

Sorry just to update, I mean this when you are viewing the orders in the backend of Magento,

Regards.

Comment: Yes, you need to override the corresponding adminhtml block and phtml files to cater for this. Start with blocks Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Items_Renderer_Default and Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Items and their phtml files.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to work a solution for this, I did a full update to the database table putting Fullname | type and exploding on the views I only wanted the type.